# RMI error trying to run sample LiveCycle code on JBoss

Tags: java, jboss, adobe, rmi, livecycle

I have Adobe LiveCycle ES4 Server running on JBoss on a Windows 7 machine.  On another Windows machine within the same network, I set up a client also running on JBoss, but probably a newer version (7.1.1).  Using sample code provided by Adobe, I am trying to test my connection over RMI, but am running into errors.  Here is the stack trace:

```
14:57:40,226 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.proxy.ClientContainer from [Module "deployment.jboss-as-kitchensink-jsp.war:main" from Service Module Loader] (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
14:57:40,226 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClass(Unknown Source)
14:57:40,227 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClass(Unknown Source)
14:57:40,227 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader$2.loadClass(Unknown Source)
14:57:40,228 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
14:57:40,228 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at sun.rmi.server.MarshalInputStream.resolveClass(Unknown Source)
14:57:40,228 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(Unknown Source)
14:57:40,229 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(Unknown Source)
14:57:40,229 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
14:57:40,230 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
14:57:40,230 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
14:57:40,231 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
14:57:40,231 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
14:57:40,231 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
14:57:40,232 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
14:57:40,232 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at java.rmi.MarshalledObject.get(Unknown Source)
14:57:40,233 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at org.jnp.interfaces.MarshalledValuePair.get(MarshalledValuePair.java:72)
14:57:40,233 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:816)
14:57:40,234 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2)   ... 29 more
```

Here is my code:

```
protected void applyUsageRights() {

    try {

        //Set connection properties required to invoke LiveCycle                                 
        Properties connectionProps = new Properties(); 
        connectionProps.setProperty(ServiceClientFactoryProperties.DSC_DEFAULT_EJB_ENDPOINT, "jnp://113.252.20.43:1099"); 
        connectionProps.setProperty(ServiceClientFactoryProperties.DSC_TRANSPORT_PROTOCOL,ServiceClientFactoryProperties.DSC_EJB_PROTOCOL);           
        connectionProps.setProperty(ServiceClientFactoryProperties.DSC_SERVER_TYPE, "JBoss"); 
        connectionProps.setProperty(ServiceClientFactoryProperties.DSC_CREDENTIAL_USERNAME, MY_USER); 
        connectionProps.setProperty(ServiceClientFactoryProperties.DSC_CREDENTIAL_PASSWORD, MY_PASSWORD); 

        //Create a ServiceClientFactory object 
        ServiceClientFactory myFactory = ServiceClientFactory.createInstance(connectionProps); 

        //Create a ReaderExtensionsServiceClient object 
        ReaderExtensionsServiceClient reClient = new ReaderExtensionsServiceClient(myFactory);  

        //Retrieve the PDF document to which to apply usage rights 
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("C:\\sample.pdf");  
        Document inputPDF = new Document(fileInputStream); 

        //Create a UsageRight object and specify specific usage rights 
        UsageRights useRight = new UsageRights();  
        useRight.setEnabledDynamicFormFields(true); 
        useRight.setEnabledComments(true); 
        useRight.setEnabledFormFillIn(true); 
        useRight.setEnabledDigitalSignatures(true); 

        //Create a ReaderExtensionsOptions object 
        ReaderExtensionsOptionSpec reOptions = new ReaderExtensionsOptionSpec();  

        //Set the usage rights  
        reOptions.setUsageRights(useRight);  
        reOptions.setMessage("This is a Rights-Enabled PDF Document"); 

        //Apply usage rights to a PDF document 
        Document rightsEnabledPDF = reClient.applyUsageRights( 
           inputPDF, 
           "RE2", 
          null, 
          reOptions);  

        //Create a new PDF file that represents the rights-enabled PDF document 
        File resultFile = new File("C:\\Adobe\\LoanUsageRights.pdf");  
        rightsEnabledPDF.copyToFile(resultFile); 

      }catch (Exception e) { 
           e.printStackTrace(); 
      }         
    }
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?  I know my client computer can access the LiveCycle server because I'm able to access a service I created in Workbench using REST (by just cutting and pasting the URL Workbench provides into my client computer's browser).  Is it because I'm using the wrong EJB Port?  1099 is the default according to the sample code but I'm not sure how to check if it's right and don't know much about JNDI.  Does it have something to do with security settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception clearly says 'it couldn't find the class' - `org.jboss.proxy.ClientContainer` .You are definitely missing the required jboss-client.jar file. Please add it to the classpath. This [link](https://community.jboss.org/thread/40141?start=0&tstart=0) has the solution. Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks! I did have the jbossall-client.jar file in my classpath, but apparently that just references other jar files that I didn't have in my classpath.  once I just copied over the entire folder of jar files, this error disappeared, but another one popped up :(.  one step at a time..